# How can I locally save an Tensorflow model from Google Colab?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have a trained encoder-decoder model on a locally-hosted JupyterLab notebook, being used via Google Colab. The model generates text captions for images. I'm looking for how to save the trained model so I can shut down my computer/use it for other tasks, without losing the trained model.

Below is the definition of the encoder class and my decoder class. My current "hunch" is that I should store the content of the 'encoder' and 'decoder' variables at the bottom, along with my dataset objects.

```py
class VGG19_Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
  # This encoder passes the features through a Fully connected layer
  def __init__(self, embedding_dim):
    super(VGG19_Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(embedding_dim)
    self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
 
  def call(self, x):
    x = self.fc(x)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)
    return x

class Rnn_Local_Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, embedding_dim, units, vocab_size):
    super(Rnn_Local_Decoder, self).__init__()
    self.units = units
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
    
    self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.units)
  
    self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
    self.batchnormalization = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001, center=True, scale=True, beta_initializer='zeros', gamma_initializer='ones', moving_mean_initializer='zeros', moving_variance_initializer='ones', beta_regularizer=None, gamma_regularizer=None, beta_constraint=None, gamma_constraint=None)
  
    self.fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
  
    #Attention Mechanism
    self.Uattn = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.Wattn = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.Vattn = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
  
  def call(self, x, features, hidden):
    hidden_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(hidden, 1)
    score = self.Vattn(tf.nn.tanh(self.Uattn(features) + self.Wattn(hidden_with_time_axis)))
    attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)
    context_vector = attention_weights * features
    context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)
    x = self.embedding(x)
    x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)
    output, state = self.gru(x)
    x = self.fc1(output)
    x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[2]))
    # Adding Dropout and Batch Normalisaton Layers
    x= self.dropout(x)
    x= self.batchnormalization(x)
    x = self.fc2(x)
    
    return x, state, attention_weights
  
  def reset_state(self, batch_size):
    return tf.zeros((batch_size, self.units))

#Assign the encoder and decoder used in training
encoder = VGG19_Encoder(embedding_dim)
decoder = Rnn_Local_Decoder(embedding_dim, units, vocab_size)
```

For further context I'll also include the function used to generate a caption based on a given image. Its use of the 'encoder' and 'decoder' objects is the reason for my "hunch" mentioned above.

```py
def generate_prediction(image):
  #attention_plot = np.zeros((max_length, 49))
  attention_plot = np.zeros((10, 49))

  hidden = decoder.reset_state(batch_size=1)
  temp_input = tf.expand_dims(load_image(image)[0], 0)
  img_tensor_val = image_features_extract_model(temp_input)
  img_tensor_val = tf.reshape(img_tensor_val, (img_tensor_val.shape[0], -1, img_tensor_val.shape[3]))

  features = encoder(img_tensor_val)
  dec_input = tf.expand_dims([tokenizer.word_index['<start>']], 0)
  result = []

  for i in range(10):
    predictions, hidden, attention_weights = decoder(dec_input, features, hidden)
    attention_plot[i] = tf.reshape(attention_weights, (-1, )).numpy()
    predicted_id = tf.argmax(predictions[0]).numpy()
    #Add predicted word to 'result' output
    result.append(tokenizer.index_word[predicted_id])

    #If the last word was '<end>', stop predicting new words and output the predication & attn plot
    if tokenizer.index_word[predicted_id] == '<end>':
      return result, attention_plot

    dec_input = tf.expand_dims([predicted_id], 0)
  attention_plot = attention_plot[:len(result), :]

  return result, attention_plot
```

Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Colab notebook is running locally you should be able to save the models simply using [`save()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save):

```py
encoder.save("/path/to/encoder.keras")
decoder.save("/path/to/decoder.keras")
```